# Get maxRequestLength value from specific location path in config

Tags: config, maxrequestlength

I have several different maxRequestLengths set for different location paths. How do I get the value of the specific location path that I am looking for?

Here is what is in config: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;

class DisplayLocationInfo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationLocationCollection myLocationCollection = config.Locations;
        foreach (ConfigurationLocation myLocation in myLocationCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Location Path: {0}", myLocation.Path);
            Configuration myLocationConfiguration = myLocation.OpenConfiguration();
            Console.WriteLine("Location Configuration File Path: {0}", myLocationConfiguration.FilePath);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationlocation(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: As soon as I hit the first OpenExeConfiguration I get error: exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe

The application is .NET 4.0

Comment: Also, using web.config